Get user by email in different places
I need to retrieve all the user who has emails in different locations. The email could be in
{
...
mail: "my@email.com",
...
}

or
{
...
otherMails: ["my@email.com"],
...
}

I tried the url like
https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=mail eq 'my@email.com' or any(otherMails: mail eq 'my@email.com')

but its giving error:
"value": "')' or ',' expected at position 48 in 'mail eq 'my@email.com' or any(otherMails: mail eq 'my@email.com')'."


Are you using Azure AD Graph API? Did you try running the query in Graph Explorer?

I m not sure how to try Graph Explorer. all I need is to provide value to $filter in the url so that I can get list of users having email either in mail or otherMails.

Try this query GET https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=mail eq 'my@email.com' or otherMails/any(mail: mail eq 'my@email.com') and let me know if it works :)

Agree with @Sridevi, the correct syntax for any is otherMails/any(x:x eq '')

In my case, I ran below MS Graph query in Graph Explorer and got same error like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=mail eq 'sri@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com' or any(otherMails: mail eq 'sri@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com')

Response:

To resolve the error, I ran below modified query and got the results successfully as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'sri@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com' or otherMails/any(mail: mail eq 'sri@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com')

Response:

In your case, the error occurred as you are using incorrect syntax in your query. To resolve it, make use of below modified query:
GET https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=mail eq 'my@email.com' or otherMails/any(mail: mail eq 'my@email.com')

Reference:
Query and Paging Filters Options with Azure AD Graph API Supported | Microsoft
